# How to insert list of different length to excel file using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

> How to insert list of different length to excel file using python?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

list1=["a","b","c"]
list2=["d","e","f","g"]

df['col1'] = list1
df['col2'] = list2

df.to_excel('output.xlsx',index = False)
```

> Expected Output:

```
col1   col2
a      d
b      e
c      f
       g
```

Comment: My code works only for equal length of list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `list` into `pd.Series` and use `pd.concat`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

list1=pd.Series(["a","b","c"])
list2=pd.Series(["d","e","f","g"])

df = pd.concat([list1,list2], ignore_index=True, axis=1)

df.to_excel('output.xlsx',index = False)
```

output:

```
     0  1                                                                                                                                      
0    a  d                                                                                                                                      
1    b  e                                                                                                                                      
2    c  f                                                                                                                                      
3  NaN  g
```

Comment: but i want along with the column name

Comment: use `df.columns = ['col1', 'col2']`